# Can I assign a suffix to my custom value type?

Tags: c#, struct, value-type

For money I am using a custom value type which holds only one `decimal` field. Simplified code is as follows.

```
public struct Money
{
    private decimal _value;

    private Money(decimal money)
    {
        _value = Math.Round(money, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    }

    public static implicit operator Money(decimal money)
    {
        return new Money(money);
    }

    public static explicit operator decimal(Money money)
    {
        return money._value;
    }
}
```

While using this struct in my project sometimes an ambiguity arises. And also sometimes I am setting an `object` with a constant number which is supposed to be a `Money`. For now I am initializing the object like,

```
object myObject=(Money)200;
```

Can I assign a suffix for my custom type `Money`. I'd like to initialize the object with the following.

```
object myObject=200p;
```

Comment: No, this is not possible in C#. You could write a preprocessor to do that however.

Comment: You can't. Btw what `p` means? Pounds?

Comment: Maybe you could write yourself a constructor or implicit operator with a string parameter and parse it manually inside.

Comment: Why you are using `object` in this way at all?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy :) `p` stands for `Para` which is `Money` in turkish.

Comment: @Tarec I can do that but same problem arises. Now there will be an ambiguity if it is a `string` or `Money`. Still I have to cast.

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to tweak the Roslyn compiler to add this special case? Update the numeric literal parser to recognize the `p` token suffix and replace it with a cast to `(Money)` (or invoke the `Money` constructor with it) EDIT: Of course, at this point the code is only viable/buildable with your internal usage. But maybe that's ok for your intended usage.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Interesting point. Are we able to modify the compiler?

Comment: @serdar: Yup, it was made open-source not too long ago: https://roslyn.codeplex.com/

Comment: @ChrisSinclair thank you, I'll study it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't assign custom suffixes with C#. The closest thing you can do is creating extension method for integers:

```
public static Money Para(this int value) // you can do same for decimals
{
   return (Money)((decimal)value);
}
```

Usage:

```
var amount = 200.Para();
```

Comment: What is the advantage of this over `(Money)200`?

Comment: @serdar IntelliSense. You just print dot-p-tab and its done (sorry, unfortunately its not working with integer literals without brackets). Also for me it is readable like plain text